# Segmentation fault in codechef submission

Tags: c

**Problem**

Given N and M Dexter wants to know how many pairs a,b(1 <= a < b <=N) are there such that (a+b) is divisible by M.
For example when N=4 and M=3, there are 2 possible pairs the sum of which is divisible by M and they are (1,2) and (2,4).
Input

First line of input contains T(<=100000) which is the number of test cases. Each of the next T lines contains two integers N(1 <= N <= 10^9) and M(2 <= M <= 10^9).
Output

Output one line per testcase, the number of pairs (a,b) as described before.

**This is a problem from codechef.After submitting the answer I am getting segmentation fault error.please help me with the right answer.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int i,t,flag,j,x,k,m[100],n[100];
  scanf("%d",&t);
  for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
    scanf("%d %d",&n[i],&m[i]);

  for(x=1;x<=t;x++){
    k=1;
    flag=0;

    for(i=m[x];i<=((2*n[x])-1);i=(m[x]*k)){
      for(j=1;j<=(i/2);j++){
        if(((i-j)<=n[x]) && (j!=(i-j))){
          flag=flag+1;
        }
      }
      k++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",flag);
  }
}
```

Comment: Run the code in `gdb` or a similar debugger. It will let you print a stack trace of the segfault.

Comment: Please use spaces and newlines more generously. Your code is so compact, it is almost impossible to read. It's not like your program will run slower, or you'll run out of hard disk space.

Comment: In C, arrays `a[N]` are indexed starting at index 0 up to N-1. Idiomatic C therefore normally runs loops `for (i = 0; i < N; i++)`.  It also avoids crashing out of bounds of the array.  While it is OK to use other loops for special purposes, you should generally aim for the `for (i = 0; i < N; i++)` notation when running through arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the problem statement, `T` could be up to 100000. When `T` is above 100, the following statement

```
scanf("%d %d",&n[i],&m[i]);
```

produces undefined behavior, because both `n` and `m` are sized at 100.

Since each test case can be processed in isolation, you do not need `n` and `m` arrays at all: replace them by scalar variables `m` and `n`, remove the first `for` loop, and call `scanf` inside the second loop:

```
int i,t,flag,j,x,k,m,n;
scanf("%d",&t);
for(x=1;x<=t;x++) {
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    ...
}
```

Note: this will solve the crash, but you would need to work on getting the speed of your algorithm to acceptable levels.

Comment: @user3424954 You should be able to replace the innermost loop by providing a closed-form answer to this question: "Given a number `n` and a number `i` in the range `1..2*n-1`,how many ordered pairs from the range `1..n` add up to `i`?" Start with counting unordered pairs, then divide that number by two. It may help to consider situations when `i <= n` and `i > n` separately.